# Why PostgreSQL changes the query plan?

Tags: postgresql, explain

I'm creating a table with date column`(data type -> timestamp with time zone)`.
And the date column is indexed;

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "start_month_idx" ON test (date_part('month',(start_date AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')));
```

And try this,

```
EXPlAIN ANALYZE SELECT
      id
FROM 
      test
WHERE 
   
     date_part('month', start_date AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') = date_part('month',current_timestamp );
```

I run this query several times.Sometimes it performs sequential scan and sometimes index scan.

**Sequential scan**

```
"Seq Scan on test  (cost=0.00..115.00 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=1.434..2.219 rows=1000 loops=1)"
"Filter: ((date_part('month'::text, start_date) = date_part('month'::text, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)))"
"Rows Removed by Filter: 2000"
"Planning Time: 0.062 ms"
"Execution Time: 2.266 ms"
```

**Index scan**

```
"Index Scan using ""start_month_idx"" on test  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.020..0.194 rows=1000 loops=1)"
"Index Cond: ((date_part('month'::text, timezone('UTC'::text, start_date)) = date_part('month'::text, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)))"
"Planning Time: 0.100 ms"
"Execution Time: 0.242 ms"
```

What is the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the different execution plans as formatted text (make sure you preserve the indention of the plan!). Btw. "Seq Scan" is short for "sequential scan", not "sequence scan"

Comment: How many rows are there in the table?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver 3000 rows

Comment: For that small a table the planner would probably find a seq scan the better choice most of the time. The fact that it uses an index scan sometimes is most likely due to whatever the most recent stats are. Does the data in this table change much?

Comment: It changes daily.

Comment: Then I would throw an `ANALYZE` at it right after it changes, though I'm still not sure it is big enough to really matter.

Comment: Yeah I checked this.Right after table changes it performs index scan.